# Why a local variable is updating itself?

Tags: python, list, variables

I am having the following code:

```
file = open('MyCSV.csv') # this read the Headers name
reader = csv.reader(file)
Data = next(reader,None)
Data = Data[1:]
DataTmp = Data


for item in DataM: # DataM is a list with one element from Data
    Data.remove(item) #remove one item


#
print(len(Data))
print(len(DataTmp))
```

So, I open `MyCSV.csv` file, read the header line, and store it in the variable `Data`. I also made a copy of `Data` by `DataTmp`. Originally, the list `Data` has 10 elements.

Then, I removed one element from `Data`.

Now, I expect that the length of `Data` is `9` and the length of `DataTmp` is still `10`. However, I get the answer that the length of `DataTmp` is `9` too. Why? I never changed `DataTmp` and I defined it before I remove an element from `Data`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `DataTmp = Data` makes those the *same object*. That doesn't make a copy. Effecting one will effect the other.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you! Now I understood. I used to use Matlab instead of python, and I guess this is the first 'big' difference I learned.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure only a few days ago I saw a similar question from someone else coming from MATLAB. This seems to be a common point of confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important change is

```
import copy
```

AND

```
DataTmp = copy.copy(Data) # Use this instead of direct assignment.
```

INSTEAD OF

```
DataTmp = Data
```

Use below code.

```
import copy

file = open('MyCSV.csv') # this read the Headers name
reader = csv.reader(file)
Data = next(reader,None)
Data = Data[1:]
# DataTmp = Data
DataTmp = copy.copy(Data) # Use this instead of direct assignment.

for item in DataM: # DataM is a list with one element from Data
    Data.remove(item) #remove one item

#
print(len(Data))
print(len(DataTmp))
```